# How do I stop my backtracking algorithm once I find and answer?

Tags: python, recursion, backtracking

I have wrote this code for solving a problem given to me in class, the task was to solve the ["toads and frogs problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toads_and_Frogs) using backtracking. My code solves this problem but does not stop once it reaches the solution (it keeps printing "states" showing other paths that are not a solution to the problem), is there a way to do this?. This is the code:

```
def solution_recursive(frogs):
    #Prints the state of the problem (example: "L L L L _ R R R R" in the starting case
    #when all the "left" frogs are on the left side and all the "right" frogs are on
    #the right side)
    show_frogs(frogs)

    #If the solution is found, return the list of frogs that contains the right order
    if frogs == ["R","R","R","R","E","L","L","L","L"]:
        return(frogs)

    #If the solution isn't the actual state, then start (or continue) recursion
    else:

        #S_prime contains possible solutions to the problem a.k.a. "moves"
        S_prime = possible_movements(frogs)

        #while S_prime contains solutions, do the following
        while len(S_prime) > 0:
            s = S_prime[0]
            S_prime.pop(0)
            #Start again with solution s
            solution_recursive(s)
```

Thanks in advancement!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I stop my backtracking algorithm once I find an answer?

You could use Python [exception facilities](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#exceptions) for such a purpose.

You could also adopt the convention that your `solution_recursive` returns a boolean telling to stop the backtrack.

It is also a matter of taste or of opinion.

Comment: Isn't there a more "fancy" way of doing it? I feel like exceptions would be an ugly solution.

Comment: We disagree then. I am teaching Python at [ENPC](https://www.ecoledesponts.fr/), and I taught yesterday (oct.12, 2020) that exceptions are on the opposite well suited for that case.

Comment: Thank you then! I'll try this out using sys.exit(0), would this be correct in your opinion?

Comment: Not in general. A well designed library should not `sys.exit` except on very rare cases. It should report failure to the caller code

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to expand a bit on your recursive code.

One of your problems is that your program displays paths that are not the solutions. This is because each call to `solution_recursive` starts with

```
show_frogs(frogs)
```

regardless of whether `frogs` is the solution or not.

Then, you say that the program is continuing even after the solution has been found. There are two reasons for this, the first being that your while loop doesn't care about whether the solution has been found or not, it will go through all the possible moves:

```
while len(S_prime) > 0:
```

And the other reason is that you are reinitializing `S_prime` every time this function is called. I'm actually quite amazed that it didn't enter an infinite loop just checking the first move over and over again.

Since this is a problem in class, I won't give you an exact solution but these problems need to be resolved and I'm sure that your teaching material can guide you.

Comment: The show_frogs bit is because the assignment ask us to show every state of the problem to show that the program is actually using backtracking.

The while part could be changed I think but I was being guided by a pseudocode they showed us in class, the idea is that every recursion creates a list of the movements you can do in a given position so it tries every possible position before reaching the solution (i.e. doing backtracking).

Maybe I'm doing it wrong though, what is your opinion? :)

Comment: Oh, I see. I think I misinterpreted what `possible_movements` did. Then the infinite loop is avoided so that is good. I think you should think about how to modify the while loop so that it doesn't keep on looping when the solution has been found. Why are you returning `frogs`?